# C#: How to read lines from text file and output them split by comma in another text file

Tags: c#

I have text file that contains different string, each string in a separate line like
1
2
3
I need a C# code the takes input and output file, read the text input and replace the break line by comma so the output file should contain
1,2,3 after running the code

Comment: How large is the file? It matters because if its tiny you can do it all in memory with very little code otherwise you will need a streamed approach

Comment: Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly

Comment: @Daniel it's about 3k lines

Answer (score 2):

write some code like this

```
for each line in the file
  add line to a stringbuilder
  add, to stringbuilder

write stringbuilder.ToString() to new text file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string line;
var str=new List<string>();
// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   str.Add(line);
}

file.Close();

return string.Join(",",str);
```

Look here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/aa287535(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

To borrow from this answer: [C#: How to read lines from text file and output them split by comma in another text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580763/c-how-to-read-lines-from-text-file-and-output-them-split-by-comma-in-another-t)

```
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"c:\temp\test.txt")) 
{
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    parser.SetDelimiters("\n");
    string csvData = "";
    while (!parser.EndOfData) 
    {
        //Processing row
        string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
        foreach (string field in fields) 
        {
            csvString += field + ",";
        }
        csvString += "\n";
    }
}
```

where csvString is your answer

Comment: should not really do += on a string, its expensive, user stringbuilder

Answer (score -1):

If the file is relatively small, then perhaps a one-liner solution?

```
File.WriteAllText (@"c:\path\file2.txt", String.Join (",", File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\path\file1.txt")));
```